# LAN through Ethernet is not working

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I am connected to a LAN. I am able to connect to it by WiFi but I am unable to connect it by ethernet cable. I have dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 8.Everything works fine in Windows 8.But I am unable to use it in Ubuntu. The output of `lshw -C net` is

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 50:7b:9d:d6:94:fb
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:a7:95:a4:22:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.8.171 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff
```

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:7b:9d:d6:94:fb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:322 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30856 (30.8 KB)  TX bytes:72032 (72.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18095859 (18.0 MB)  TX bytes:18095859 (18.0 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a8:a7:95:a4:22:3b  
          inet addr:192.168.8.171  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::24ac:ff57:68ab:7f44/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4903501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51878 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:434024015 (434.0 MB)  TX bytes:9039737 (9.0 MB)
```

Comment: Your output shows that the hardware is there. If its a configuration issue you need to provide information about your configuration like did you use the GUI or the command line setup using /etc/network/interfaces. Your settings might help and what you actually did to test connection.

Comment: actually I tried to open a local page on the network in chrome,then I tried to open it in firefox but it did not open

Comment: Tell me the information that I need to provide to solve it

Comment: well, where and how did you setup you LAN? Did you enter an IP address anywhere? You could post the output of the command 'ifconfig'

Comment: I did not setup the LAN, I am connected to it.It is LAN of my university.Through it we get access to internet as well.

Comment: I have added output of `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from the ifconfig output your problem is that you did not set up your LAN.

You can see in the last block that you have an IP address for your wifi (192.168.8.171). You LAN (section enp1s0) does not have that. That means your network is not configured. You have not IP address, so I can not work.

You need to Create a new network connection, provide DHCP or Manual Setup and data possibly data like IP address, Network Mask, DNS Server and Gateway address.

Network Configuration in Ubuntu is a very basic task that can be done from the GUI. You will need information from your Unviversity about the Parameters to use, likely DHCP, but I would not know. 
There are excellent descriptions including pictured of the dialogs and what to put where, imho it would not be useful to reitereate it here in full length. As they are plenty of sources, please consider looking up the Ubuntu users guide, wiki or Youtube tutorials on "Ubuntu LAN Setup" or "Ubuntu Ehternet setup". I am almost sure your university will provide to How-To sections on how to configure the network, maybe thats you best bet because it will give your the correct parameters as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Earlier it was working,it stopped working suddenly due to a power interrupt to the switch.But it works fine in windows.Earlier I used it without setting it up.